# Read message sent after command start

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a sort of trivia bot but the problem is that I can't get it working. I have it so that when you type "-quiz" it sends a embed with a random question. Now you might say that I need to make a separate JSON file and put the questions and answers there, the problem is, is that I need variables in those strings and when I tried it, it wouldn't work because the order or something like that. I tried to fix that but it seems like a bad solution anyway. I set it up so it looks for a message after the initial commands, problem is that it reads it's own embed and I honestly don't know how to make it skip bot messages

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'quiz'){

        var TypeID = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 11))
        var toLog = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))

        { //there is something here that is used for the variables above but it is super long
        }
        
        var question = [`Question one`, `Question two`]
        var answers = [[Answer1_1, Answer1_2],[Answer1_1]]

        if(toLog === 0){

            const quizEmbed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#0099ff')
                .setTitle('quiz')
                .setDescription(`${question[0]}`)               

            message.channel.send(quizEmbed1)
            if(!message.content || message.author.bot) return;
                if(message.content === [answers[0], answers[1], answers[2], answers[3], answers[4], answers[5]]){
                    message.channel.send('Good Job! That is right!')
                }else{
                    message.channel.send('Oops! that is wrong.')
                }

        }else if(toLog == 1){

            const quizEmbed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#0099ff')
                .setTitle('quiz')
                .setDescription(`${question[1]}`)

            message.channel.send(quizEmbed2)
            if(!message.content || message.author.bot) return;
                if(message.content === [answers[6]]){
                    message.channel.send('Good Job! That is right!')
                }else{
                    message.channel.send('Oops! That is wrong.')
            }
        }
        

    }


});
```

if something it wrong it is most likely because I changed it to make it smaller, I am fairly newer to coding in JavaScript

Comment: DJS stands for Discord JavaScript. Don't get Java and JavaScript mixed up

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [MessageCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector). There is a good guide on the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors)

Or using [awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages). Again there is a guide on the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages)

Here is the example using awaitMessages

```js
const filter = response => {
    return item.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
};

message.channel.send(item.question).then(() => {
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`);
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send('Looks like nobody got the answer this time.');
        });
});
```

Comment: This is the exact same thing I tried and I never got it working, I needed variables in the strings and they were never defined no matter what I did. one option is to hard code every single iteration which I rather wait till I have no other option

Comment: "I needed variables in the strings and they were never defined" can you explain what you mean? did you create a quiz.json file like shown in the guide?

Comment: Yes I made a quiz.json file as I stated in the first post. when I tried it with variables it wouldn't work. they would say the variables were undefined no matter what I did. I have variables that choose a random number then if it is a certain number then it will have a certain name and 3 things that correspond to that name. they are stored in to variables and for the sake of simplicity var a is the name and var b is the 3 things. it would ask a question like "if the name is (a) then what are the 3 things that correspond to it" then you would type those 3 things aka var b